# Decrementing an iterator

Tags: c++

I have a normal iterator to a position in a bidirectional data structure (vector in fact). Now I want to perform an operation on the past x elements from my current position. There will always be at least x elements before, although the last x may be the first element of the vector.

I have written this code

```
vector<Record>::iterator it = itCurrentRecord;
for (unsigned int i = 0; i < length; i++)
{
    (it--)->length = length;
}
```

Is this safe? I am concerned that when it points to the first element, the final decrement will cause the iterator to point to one before the first element, which is invalid.

If so, how can I rewrite this in a safe way?

Thanks

Comment: Your concern about pointing to one-before-begin is valid (invalid iterator).

Comment: @MarkB: Yes the iterator is invalid. But is it UB. If it is just unspecified then it is OK as long as the iterator is never used again.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Use a reverse iterator:

```
vector<Record>::reverse_iterator it = itCurrentRecord;
for (unsigned int i = 0; i < length; i++)
{
    (it++)->length = length;
}
```

which allows to semantically point to one-before-begin like a normal iterator is allowed to point one-past-end.

Comment: That is wrong: "which allows to point to one-before-begin like a normal iterator is allowed to point one-past-end"

Comment: @DieterLücking Why? Isn't that exactly what `end()` or `rend()` return?

Comment: It is not wrong. `rend` points to 1 element before the array (just like `end` points to 1 beyond the array):  http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/rend/

Comment: @ZacHowland: the iterators point to one-before or one-after the first or last element of a *range* - a range need not be an array.

Comment: A reverse_iterator(container.end()) points to the end of that container. Dereferencing it is basically *(iterator-1). A reverse iterator never points before begin (Assume the container has allocated at the very beginning of memory)

Comment: @ZacHowland: That's not a reference you can use to win an argument as it is non normative (its fine for a quick check only). If you are going to quote references quote the standard.

Comment: @DieterLücking Nitpicking, understood. But this is what the reverse iterator *stores*, not what it *semantically represents*. OK, I understand what you are saying but it doesn't mean the OPs initial concern wasn't valid or that there is a problem with my suggested solution.

Comment: @Please fix the misleading

Comment: @thokra:  in the case of vectors (as it is here), "range" and "array" are the same thing.

Comment: @ZacHowland: i didn't say you were wrong in this particular case. in general, however, your suggestion simply doesn't hold. just wanted to bring that to mind.

Comment: @LokiAstari:  24.5.1:  "The fundamental relation between a reverse
iterator and its corresponding iterator i is established by the identity: &*(reverse_iterator(i)) == &*(i - 1)."  In other words, if i == 0, `rend()` equals 1 item before the first item in the range/array.

Comment: @DieterLücking: "A reverse iterator never points before begin": actually it does, at least with g++ and clang. For instance, for a `std::vector<int>` the following holds: `(&*intVec.rend () + 1) == (&*intVec.begin())`.

Comment: @DieterLücking: Then I must have misunderstood "A reverse iterator never points before begin".

Comment: @ZacHowland: Perfect.

Answer (score 4):

Your concern is valid. Since this is a random access iterator, you can use arithmetic to avoid the undefined behavior:

```
vector<Record>::iterator it = itCurrentRecord;
for (unsigned int i = 0; i < length; i++)
{
    (it - i)->length = length;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can start `it` at the beginning of the range and iterate forward.

```
vector<Record>::iterator it = std::prev(itCurrentRecord, length - 1);
for (unsigned int i = 0; i < length; i++)
{
    (it++)->length = length;
}
```

Note: `std::prev` is a C++11 feature.

Comment: In this particular example order doesn't matter, but it makes a more interesting question if you assume it does.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the solutions already mentioned, you could do something like:

```
// assume vector<Record> v is filled;
vector<Record>::iterator it = currentRecord;
for_each(v.begin(), it, [&](Record& r)
{
    r.length = length;
});
```

Or if you need/want to go backwards (e.g. if the order of the iteration matters):

```
for_each(reverse_iterator<vector<Record>::iterator>(it), v.rend(), [&](Record& r)
{
    r.length = length;
});
```