# Is decrementing std::vector::begin undefined, even if it is never used?

Tags: c++, iterator

Note that, contrary to the many questions on the subject (and probably why I can not find a satisfactory answer to this question neither on google nor on stackoverflow), I never dereference `*(begin() - 1)`

---

My requirements are to:

- iterate backwards
- use functions that do not take reverse iterators, in this example `vector::erase()`
- try to keep the code clean, so try to avoid the mental juggling of:

  `vector.erase(rev_it.base() - 1)`

  (What should the reverse iterator be now to get the the next element in the iteration ? The iterator returned by `erase()` ? `+ 1`, probably ? `- 1` , unlikely ?)

What I’ve come up with is:

```
for (auto it = vector.end(); it-- != vector.begin(); ) {
    if (condition(*it)) {
        it = vector.erase(it);
    }
}
```

This seems to work, as `it--` returns the iterator’s value and *then* only decrements it, meaning the iterator is always decremented *after the check* but *before entering the loop body*.

In particular:

#### When entering the loop

- if `vector.end() == vector.begin()` the vector is empty and we exit the loop immediately
- if `vector.end() != vector.begin()` then we enter the loop, with the first loop body execution with `it == vector.end() - 1`

#### When erasing elements

`vector.erase(it)` returns the following element in the vector, so decrementing the iterator at *every iteration* gets us to consider exactly once every element in the vector.

#### When exiting the loop

At the last execution of the loop’s body, `it == vector.begin()`, so the next time we try the loop condition:

- the condition returns `false`
- `it` is decremented one last time
- we exit the loop

That is, my code does seem to *compute* the iterator position `begin() - 1` but *never accesses it*, *nor uses it for comparisons* or anything like that.

#### Is this undefined behaviour?

Do I risk a segfault or something? Or just accessing uninitialized data maybe? Nothing at all because the iterator is discarded before being used in anyway? Is there no way of knowing?

Comment: It is undefined by omission.      In any event, why not use reverse iterators?

Comment: *"meaning the iterator is always decremented after the check but before entering the loop body"* - that's simply not true. The iterator is copied to a temp, then decremented, then the temp copy is returned by value. That's the only (and proper) way a post-decrement operator on an iterator class can be implemented.  The iterator is in UB land before the check; it's just not the iterator participating in the check to begin with; the copy is.

Comment: @WhozCraig It only *appears* that way, it’s not what happens in practice, you’re absolutely right. Let me edit that in. That doesn’t change my question’s bottom line: does this decremented undefined iterator matter?

Comment: Ultimately your question is, is it legal to apply decrement operations on a bidirectional iterator already at sequence start (i.e. begin()). To my knowledge the only container iterator that supports that is `std::forward_list`, which supports construct of a `before_begin()` iterator. You're not the first to ask this question, btw. [See here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18920662/decrementing-an-iterator). And the advice was the same as it is here: reverse iterator.

Comment: @WhozCraig Actually I might have moved the goalposts a little here, I’ll revert that. Your first comment was what I’m looking or really. Care to post that with maybe a word or two on why UB is bad even if I don’t seem to rely on its current behaviour?

Comment: You may not be "fond" of `std::prev(it).base()?` but it does work - your "constraint" to not use that is completely arbitrary.    Your argument is essentially "I don't like this hammer that has been provided, so I want to implement another one".

Comment: @Peter A hammer, really? `it = std::vector<....>::reverse_iterator(vector.erase(std::next(it).base()))`, in the most academic and readable of cases? And is it `prev` or `next`? I’m definitely willing to use a slightly less canonic loop structure if it gets me `it = vector.erase(it)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about

```
for (auto it = vector.end(); it != vector.begin(); ) {
    --it;
    ... rest of the loop body
```